# Explain what "$f$ is continuous in $x_{0}$" means in terms of limits of sequences

Tags: analysis, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Task from an exam: Explain the meaning of "$f$ is continuous in
>   $x_{0}$" in terms of limits of sequences.

I would explain it like that and please tell me if it's ok?

Let $f$ be a function which is continuous in $x_{0}$. The criteria "limits of sequences" (or however this is called... :o) says that there exists a sequence $x_{n}$ whose $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x_{0}$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(x_{n}))=x_{0}=f(x_{0})$

Please tell me is this explanation correct?

Comment: Are you sure that it says "there exists a sequence"? Can you improve it?

Comment: The phrasing is a bit strange, but the main idea is there

Comment: Glad to hear!! :))

Comment: *The idea is there*...but not quite correctly expressed. In particular, the quantifier "exists" is incorrect.

Comment: @mfl and the others: How would you write it instead? I was also not sure about it but I didn't know another way, maybe also because this is in English :p

Comment: You should say "for any sequence":

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the following: let $\;f\;$ be a function defined on $\;x_0\;$ and some neighborhood $\;I_0\;$ of it. Then, $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;x_0\;$ iff for *any sequence* $\;\{x_n\}\;$ in $\;I_0\;$ s.t.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0\;,\;\;\text{then it is true that also}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$$